# Cannot login to WordPress admin after update

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hello I need help please for my website.

I can not enter the wordpress admin after updating the version.
the hosting does not respond to me either.

This is the image that informs me, a php version problem, of an extension.

Please specify if you can help me resolve this issue.
fatal error:

> Thu Apr 13 21:34:32.422034 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 7923] [client 181.65.19.68:8284] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function wp_generate_password() in /home/aluditravel/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-recovery-mode-key-service.php on line 33: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56

muchas gracias
alejandro
[image]

Comment: please edit your question to include an english translation, this is an english speaking stack and most users will not understand your question

Comment: gracias!!!!!!!!!

Comment: thankyou, when you say WP version did you mean the PHP version? Have you made modifications to files in the `wp-includes` folder? `/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php56` implies PHP v5.6 which is very old, and `wp_generate_password` is a standard WordPress function which implies WP has been modified or is damaged

Comment: I mean the wordpress update, and not php.
The truth is that I entered WordPress, then it said to update and since I confirmed, then I could not enter again.
So I entered Cpanel and I read that the php version is very old but when I update it to version 8 and apply it, it gives me this error when I want to enter my website"It appears that your PHP installation does not have the MySQL extension, which is necessary for WordPress to function. Please check that the PHP mysqli extension is installed and activated."

Comment: you'll need to speak with your host about the mysql extension, and a WP upgrade should not prevent you from logging in ( it might log you out though, and if you've forgotten your login details then you've lost access ). You should verify and ensure that WP is unmodified and intact, you can manually replace the `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders from a fresh download of WordPress to confirm this

Comment: I sent an email to the host but they haven't responded yet."could you help me?

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope you answer me from the hosting. help is appreciated, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your PHP version to 7.2. If that gives you access, update all themees/plugins and WP to latest versions. (PHP version updates done through your hosting Control Panel. Your hosting place should have help docs on how to set your PHP version.)

Test those upgrades, then upgrade PHP to version 8.x.

There are major security issues with PHP 5.x. You should strive to keep everything current. Updating to 7.2 first should help you regain access, then you can finish upgrading to latest everything.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I updated the php to 7.2, 7.4 but I can't access WPadmin either, changing it to 8.0. It tells me that I must have the Php Mysqli extension installed and active. I did a manual wordpress update, but I can't get in either.

Comment: You will need to talk to your hosting place to get mysqli installed/available. You can also try renaming your php.ini file to php.ini.bak, so that  default values are used. Perhaps a statement in the current php.ini file is not enabling the mlsqii properly. Also, make sure you update WP core files if they are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the PHP version is compatible with WordPress (recommended: PHP 7.4 or higher).

Temporarily deactivate plugins and switch to a default theme.

Download and reinstall the latest version of WordPress.
Remove the .maintenance file or add a line to wp-config.php to disable recovery mode.

Seek support from your hosting provider, providing the error message and update details.

Remember to keep backups of your website before making any changes.